# iOS - Trouble saving subclass to Parse backend

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, instantiation, option-type

I've been trying to implement Parse in my application and can't seem to get my Subclass to save to the backend. I've been using the guides provided by Parse [here](https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#subclasses-properties/iOS) and [here](https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFObject.html#//api/name/saveInBackgroundWithBlock:) but still can't get it to work.

My Subclass looks like this:

```
import Foundation
import Bolts
import Parse

class Fillup : PFObject, PFSubclassing {

@NSManaged var username: String?
@NSManaged var amount: String?
@NSManaged var cost: String?
@NSManaged var date: NSDate?
@NSManaged var location: CLLocation?

override class func initialize() {
    var onceToken : dispatch_once_t = 0;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken) {
        self.registerSubclass()
    }
}

static func parseClassName() -> String {
    return "Fillup"
}
```

Accessing the variables works fine using `let x = fillup.amount as String!`.

However, in my save method the variables always end up being nil.

Here's a small example from my save method:

```
@IBAction func saveTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

    // instantiate new Fillup object
    var fillup :Fillup?

    //check for nil on variables
    if let username = PFUser.currentUser()?.username {

        println(username)
        fillup?.username = username

    }else{

        println("Username is nil.")

    }

    println(fillup?.username)

    //save object to backend   
    fillup?.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({ (success, error) -> Void in

        if error != nil {

            println("Error: " + error!.localizedDescription)

        }else{

            println("Fillup saved!")

        }            
    })      
}
```

The output always looks like:

```
mforrest3
nil
```

and as the variable is nil it doesn't save successfully to the backend.

I've not included the code for the other variables for simplicity's sake however I think this should still work.

If anyone could point me in the direction of a good guide or help me come up with an answer/reason that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
var fillup :Fillup?
```

Is not creating a new instance, it's just defining an optional local variable of the appropriate type. You should have

```
var fillup = Fillup.object()
```

To actually call the constructor for the class (and allow the compiler to determine the class in this case)

Comment: This makes sense however now I get the error : `Missing argument for parameter 'className' in call`. I'm assuming this is something to do with my `parseClassName()` method in `Filler.swift` but looking at the Parse documentation [here](https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#subclasses-properties/iOS) I can't see what's wrong.

Comment: Updated answer. It seems that the subclass initialisation requires `.object` to be called rather than the base constructor...

Comment: That line brings up the error `'object()' is unavailable: use object construction 'PFObject()'`, when changing the line to `var fillup = Fillup.PFObject()` it comes up with the error `'Fillup.Type' does not have a member named 'PFobject'`.

Comment: Seems like that's a bug. Which leaves using the className approach, which sucks